# Django Query set: Duration from two DateTimeField()

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

In my Django project, I have a model like this-

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ticket_number = models.CharField()
    order_number = models.CharField()
    number_of_errors = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'd like to make a query set "tasks" where I'll include working_date, ticket_number, order_number, and work_hours(end_time-start_time) in HH:MM:SS for example 03:55:01 format. "working_date" will be derived from end_time. Once I get the query set right, I'll export the result in a CSV.

I can do the query in MySQL like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(end_time) AS working_date,
    ticket_number, order_number, TIME_FORMAT((TIMEDIFF(end_time,start_time)),'%H:%i:%s') AS work_hours
FROM
    task
WHERE
    end_time>= pStartDate AND end_time< pEndDate;
```

How do I do this in Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, fields


duration = ExpressionWrapper(F('end_time') - F('start_time'), output_field=fields.DurationField())
task_list = Task.objects.all().annotate(duration=duration)
```

So, suppose you loop through tasks and wat to find the duration

```
for task in task_list:
   print(task.duration)
```